# Highcharts navigator error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does anyone know why I am seeing this error - **"error: Invalid negative value for  attribute width"** while using the Highstock navigator? Please see this JsFiddle for my code - http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/250/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        height: 120
    },
    navigator: {
        series: {
            data: chartData
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [null],
        markers: {
            enabled:true
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: I think it's because your series data is null.  If you add data to the series, the error goes away.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird yes but if you do that, the rangeselector becomes un-usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is all on one day. The minRange of highstock is one day by default.  So, the reason it appears your rangeselector is unusable when you have your data correctly defined within the series is that you are already zoomed into one day.
Move the data from the navigator to a series and change the xAxis minRange to be a smaller number (I choose 1 minute)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    series: [{
        data: chartData,
        markers: {
            enabled:true
        }
    }],
    xAxis : {
        minRange: 60 * 1000 // one minute
    },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/Yrygy/256/

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want the main chart to be visible, just want the navigator. How do I set the series but hide it?

Comment: Well, I guess you could set your height back to 120 http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/257/

Comment: Thank you :) Would you please look at another question I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765477/highstock-navigator-does-not-work-when-also-importing-highcharts-more-file

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when I used `navigator.series.setData()`. All you need is set min and max values with `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)`