# Highstock navigator does not work when also importing "highcharts-more" file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does anyone know why this is happening? If I remove this -

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

The navigator data series renders fine, but if I add it, the data series stops rendering and only the range selector shows. Please help.
My jsfiddle - (does not work) https://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/258/

[image]Jsfiddle    - (works) https://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/257/
[image]

Comment: That's odd.  If you increase your size to 200, it shows up again. I know that's not what you want, but it might help someone with debugging it.

Comment: Well it works for me, how we can replicate this issue?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I was able to reproduce it in safari. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @SebastianBochan please open my jsfiddle links in chrome, one works and one does not.

Comment: Well in both cases, still works, also in the Safari.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I edited the question to show you what I am seeing.  Are you seeing the line in the 1st case?

Comment: Indeed now I see, sorry ;) Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3574)

Answer (score 1):

Reorder the scripts. Move `highcharts-more.js` above `highstock.js` and it will work.

I think the problem is because of this: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16